# parse title of other urls using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am looking for a way to get title of urls mentioned in the webpage.
I tried http://urldecoderonline.com/ but it does not provide a way to parse the page.

Just for ex: user enters a url say http://www.google.com in a text input box and on pressing a submit button i would like to alert him with a title of "http://www.google.com"

Any ideas??

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do ?

Comment: http://urldecoderonline.com/javascript-url-decode-jquery-plugin.htm

Answer (score 2):

you need to use ajax and a php ajax proxy script on your server

i didn't test this, but it should work

ajax_proxy.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["url"]){
        echo file_get_contents($_POST["url"]);
    }
?>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "text",
            url: "ajax_proxy.php",
            data: { url: $("#input").val() }
            success: function(data){
                alert($(data).find("title").html());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get title of a href link you can use `attr` function of jQuery.

```
$("a").attr("title");
```

To get titles of all links on page:

```
$("a").each(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr("title");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to extract the host part from the URL string, then this is a typical regular expression problem.

If there's something before the first semicolon, that's the protocol. Everything from there up to the forward slash is the host.

Something along the line of:

```
<http>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function parseUrl(url) {
    var regexStringProtocol = '^([A-Za-z]*)://';
    var protocolResults=new RegExp(regexStringProtocol).exec(url);
    if(protocolResults) {
        var protocol = protocolResults[1];
        url = url.substring(protocolResults[0].length);
    }
    else {
        var protocol = '';
    }
    var regexStringHost = '^([^/^?]+)';
    var hostResults = new RegExp(regexStringHost).exec(url);
    if(hostResults) {
        var host = hostResults[1];
    }
    else {
        host = '';
    }

    alert('Protocol: ' + protocol + '\nHost: ' + host);
    // Continue parsing if you care about the part and the parameters

}

$(function() {
    $('input').val('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715438/parse-title-of-other-urls-using-jquery/6715527#6715527');
    $('#parse').click(function() { parseUrl($('input').val());});
        }
    );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" style='width:150mm' />
<br />
<button id="parse">Parse</button>
</body>
</html>
```